# The official node.js deb package repository has no source packages, is it a license breach?

Tags: mit, source-code

Recently I tried to download the official node.js source debian packages, as described [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md).

For my largest surprise, their source repositories are simply *empty* (although they are part of their official apt source download list).

The (not debianized) node.js source code can be downloaded, that is okay. But their package repository, while it contains `deb-src` entries in the apt configuration file, it has no source packages.

As a quick [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) scan shows, node.js is originally in MIT license. In the case of GPL, I think it would be an obvious case, but with MIT license I am not so sure.

Can we consider it as a license breach? If yes, what would be the steps to do?

Comment: I'm not aware of any license that requires that Debian source packages be provided. What do the terms of the license say? Even GPL only says that source code must be provided on request from users.

Comment: @curiousdannii 1) The debs are derived works, usually meaning that they must follow the same license. 2) I doubt that GPL would be so loose, do you have some reference?

Comment: It's certainly weird that the source package is empty (and probably a bug), but which part of section 6 of the GPLv3 do you think is being violated?

Comment: @curiousdannii Not the source deb is empty, but their repository has no source packages. I made it clear with a post edit.

Comment: @curiousdannii node.js is not GPL, but MIT. But if it would be GPL, I think it would be an obvious breach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MIT licence](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) provides that

> Permission is hereby granted ... to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software ... subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Note the absence of any language requiring the provision of source.  So no, in this case, no licence is being violated.